# What is the conflict of TIFFImageWriterSpi?

Tags: hadoop, jar, raster, geoserver, accumulo

I am trying to setup http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html

I have this **jai_imageio-1.1.jar** at geomesa libs which contains TIFFImageWriterSpi.

when i try to ingest raster using this command:

geomesa ingestraster -u root -p qwerty -t natearth -f "/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/geoserver-2.8.3/data_dir/coverages/retile/1/NE2_HR_LC_SR_W_DR_01_01.tif" -F geotiff

Overall log:

```
Using GEOMESA_HOME = /home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/geomesa-1.2.1/dist/tools/geomesa-tools-1.2.1/
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/Installs/accumulo-1.6.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/Installs/zookeeper-3.4.8/contrib/fatjar/zookeeper-3.4.8-fatjar.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriterSpi
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.<clinit>(GeoTiffFormat.java:106)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormatFactorySpi.createFormat(GeoTiffFormatFactorySpi.java:88)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder.findFormats(GridFormatFinder.java:185)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder.findFormat(GridFormatFinder.java:236)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder.findFormat(GridFormatFinder.java:216)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.RasterIngest$class.getReader(RasterIngest.scala:57)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalRasterIngest.getReader(LocalRasterIngest.scala:26)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalRasterIngest.ingestRasterFromFile(LocalRasterIngest.scala:52)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalRasterIngest$$anonfun$runIngestTask$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LocalRasterIngest.scala:48)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalRasterIngest$$anonfun$runIngestTask$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LocalRasterIngest.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? Also, note that the JAR you mention has "com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi" which is not in the package the exception names.
BTW, a terrible hack I used to workaround the issue is putting imageio-ext in the classpath. Yikes!
https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext

Answer (score -1):

Read your error message.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/Installs/accumulo-1.6.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/Installs/zookeeper-3.4.8/contrib/fatjar/zookeeper-3.4.8-fatjar.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

[Here is the link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)

Comment: That is just a warning message. I corrected that issue. It eliminates the warning. But, it doesn't impact the error.

Comment: The log is as follows: gaurav@gaurav-XPS-8500:~/Downloads/CPSC-771/geomesa-1.2.1/dist/tools/geomesa-tools-1.2.1/lib$ geomesa ingestraster -u root -p qwerty -t natearth -f "/home/gaurav/Downloads/CPSC-771/geoserver-2.8.3/data_dir/coverages/retile/1/NE2_HR_LC_SR_W_DR_01_01.tif" -F geotiff

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriterSpi
 at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.<clinit>